# regex replace string PySpark

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a column with string values like `'{"phones":["phone1", "phone2"]}'` and i would like to remove characters and result in a string like `phone1, phone2`. I am using a regex like

```
df.withColumn('Phones',
                    F.regexp_replace(F.split(F.col('input_phones'), ':').getItem(1), r'\}', ''))
```

which returns a string like '["phone1", "phone2"]'.
Is there a way to test different regex and how to exclude other special characters?

Comment: use https://regex101.com/ or https://regexr.com/ to test your regex

Answer (score 0):

Your string (`'{"phones":["phone1", "phone2"]}'`) looks like a json, and we can parse the same in pyspark using [`from_json`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.from_json.html#pyspark-sql-functions-from-json).

```
data_sdf = spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('{"phones":["phone1", "phone2"]}',)]).toDF(['json_str'])

# json's schema
json_target_schema = StructType([
    StructField('phones', ArrayType(StringType()), True)
])

data_sdf. \
    withColumn('json_parsed', func.from_json(func.col('json_str'), json_target_schema)). \
    select('json_str', 'json_parsed.*'). \
    withColumn('phones_str', func.concat_ws(',', 'phones')). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
# |json_str                       |phones          |phones_str   |
# +-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
# |{"phones":["phone1", "phone2"]}|[phone1, phone2]|phone1,phone2|
# +-------------------------------+----------------+-------------+
```

Lets check the dataframe's schema to see the columns' data types

```
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('json_parsed', func.from_json(func.col('json_str'), json_target_schema)). \
    select('json_str', 'json_parsed', 'json_parsed.*'). \
    withColumn('phones_str', func.concat_ws(',', 'phones')). \
    printSchema()

# root
#  |-- json_str: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- json_parsed: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- phones: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |-- phones: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |-- phones_str: string (nullable = false)

# +-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
# |json_str                       |json_parsed       |phones          |phones_str   |
# +-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
# |{"phones":["phone1", "phone2"]}|{[phone1, phone2]}|[phone1, phone2]|phone1,phone2|
# +-------------------------------+------------------+----------------+-------------+
```